# Which method is called to initialize a Maven plugin before its execution?

Tags: maven, initialization

I'm writing a Maven plugin and would like to convert a set of strings inputted as parameter **excludes** to a pattern before the plugin execution. I implemented the interface **org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.Initializable** but when I access in the **initialize** method the parameter **excludes** is null in the **execute** method is not null.
  Which method is called to initialize a Maven plugin before its execution and has access to the parameters?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a separate lifecycle? special needs for that? Why not using default plugin mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation i can give is to take a deep [look into the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) which will give you the advice to define some kind of parameters and may be some default values for different parameters. The first method is usually the execute() method of the AbstractMojo class which you have to inherit from. If you need some kind of default values just check the parameters if they haven't been initialized (which means being null) and give the values you like for them.